# Where to initialize sqlite database for a user with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, sqlite.swift

I have this function that initializes a database (basically copied from the [documentation](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) of SQLite.swift).

```swift
func createDB() {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    print(documentsDirectory)
    do {
        // creates new if it doesnt exist
        let db = try Connection("\(documentsDirectory)/dbtest.sqlite3")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Right now I just have it within the `@main` struct.

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    ...
    createDB()
}
```

In the SwiftUI world, how would you create a global DB object that I can use throughout a session (user having the app open)? Or is creating it here fine?

Comment: This seems to be a purely SwiftUI question, so this is the "SwiftUI" world, not the "iOS world", and you need `swiftui` in your tags.

Comment: @matt done! Thanks :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various good / bad / ugly ways of handling this, and creating the db in main struct, may be a considered a bad way.

A better approach is to wrap all sqlite code in one of your own implementations. As an example, check [*Wrapping the Database Connection* section in  this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6620276-sqlite-with-swift-tutorial-getting-started#toc-anchor-016)

Also in the spirit of *not writing a "link only" answer*, below is a snippet  from the same section

```
class SQLiteDatabase {
    private let dbPointer: OpaquePointer?
    private init(dbPointer: OpaquePointer?) {
        self.dbPointer = dbPointer
    }
    deinit {
      sqlite3_close(dbPointer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this reference, not sure how I didn't see it. I'll take a look